# how to call multiple generator in python

Tags: python, generator

I tried the triplet loss method for partial data. each data will be entered into the model.
I made a generator for partial data. but i have a problem here.

how to get multiple generators for partial data:

```
def batch_generator(batch_size, num_part, X):
    y_val = np.zeros((batch_size, 2, 1))
    anchors = np.zeros((batch_size, num_part, input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2])) # (16,4,3,128,128)
    positives = np.zeros((batch_size, num_part, input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2])) # (16,4,3,128,128)
    negatives = np.zeros((batch_size, num_part, input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2])) # (16,4,3,128,128)

    while True:
        for i in range(batch_size):
            positiveFace = np.random.randint(len(X))
            negativeFace = np.random.randint(len(X))
            while positiveFace == negativeFace:
                negativeFace = np.random.randint(len(X))

            # Face encoding generate images to partial images (4 part)
            positives[i] = face_img_to_encoding(X[positiveFace])
            anchors[i] = face_img_to_encoding(X[positiveFace])
            negatives[i] = face_img_to_encoding(X[negativeFace])


        x_data_1 = {'anchor': anchors[:,0], # get data (16,0,3,128,128)
                  'anchorPositive': positives[:,0],
                  'anchorNegative': negatives[:,0]
                  }

        x_data_2 = {'anchor': anchors[:,1], # get data (16,1,3,128,128)
                  'anchorPositive': positives[:,1],
                  'anchorNegative': negatives[:,1]
                  }

        x_data_3 = {'anchor': anchors[:,2], # get data (16,2,3,128,128)
                  'anchorPositive': positives[:,2],
                  'anchorNegative': negatives[:,2]
                  }

        x_data_4 = {'anchor': anchors[:,3], # get data (16,3,3,128,128)
                  'anchorPositive': positives[:,3],
                  'anchorNegative': negatives[:,3]
                  }

        yield (x_data_1, [y_val, y_val, y_val])
        yield (x_data_2, [y_val, y_val, y_val])
        yield (x_data_3, [y_val, y_val, y_val])
        yield (x_data_4, [y_val, y_val, y_val])
```

when i call:

```
gen = batch_generator(BATCH_SIZE, NUM_PARTIAL, X)
print(type(gen)) #1
print(type(next(gen))) #2
print(type(next(gen))) #3
print(type(next(gen))) #4
```

its output:

```
#1 <type='generator'>
#2 <type='tuple'>
#3 <type='tuple'>
#4 <type='tuple'>
```

how to make all the generators output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just call `next(gen)` 4 times to get the values. The first creates the generator but doesn't yield a value until you call `next(gen)`:

```
gen = batch_generator(BATCH_SIZE, NUM_PARTIAL, X)
print(type(next(gen))) #1
print(type(next(gen))) #2
print(type(next(gen))) #3
print(type(next(gen))) #4
```

Alternatively, you can unpack into 4 variables:

```
gen = batch_generator(BATCH_SIZE, NUM_PARTIAL, X)
x1, x2, x3, x4 = gen
```

Is there any reason you are `yield`ing the values rather than just `return`ing them. This looks like a strange use of `yield`.

Comment: I've tried it, and there's still an error.

are there any references related to using triplet loss with multiple generators / models?